# Reading text file values for plotting - Python

Tags: python-3.x, input, plot, split, csv

I have a text file with values inside of it like so:

```
1913 - 5,588,048
1914 - 4,202,179
1915 - 1,172,258
1916 - 2,481,675
1917 - 5,521,373
1918 - 6,052,289
1919 - 7,835,400 

1920 - 1929
1920 - 10,649,851
1921 - 2,582,495
1922 - 4,763,186
```

I want a 2D plot of these two columns of numbers. 19xx and x-axis, and the other column on the y-axis. I'm having trouble using split() to get rid of the ' - ' and also removing '' that appear for some reason.

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("Nickels.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')


data2 = [row.split(' - ',1) for row in data] # to get rid of ' - '
data2[:] = [item for item in x if item != ''] # to get rid of ''


x = []
y = []
for i in range(len(x)): #making lists
    x.append(0)
    y.append(0)
for j in enumerate(data2):
    x[i] = data2[:1]

print(x1)

#will proceed after part above works.
#fig = plt.figure()
#ax1.plot(x1,y1, c='r', label='Data')
#plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please state what exactly would you like to have along the x-axis and the same for y-axis? Also, give at least 10 lines of your data file (with each line indented by four spaces).

Comment: I've edited your input section. Could you kindly confirm whether your file looks like the edited one or does it really contain blank lines?

Comment: There are a few blank lines here and there. Always before a number is about to be repeated. E.g. 1920

Comment: Was my code of use to you, Michael?

Comment: It was somewhat useful. I'm getting `'str' object has no attribute 'append' `at line  `y.append([int(x) for x in d2])`. x is good but now I want to `y.replace(',','')` and not have a list inside a list

Comment: I think you missed out the `y=[]` at the beginning.

Comment: Ok, that would be helpful. Also, any ideas how I could make the y list more like `[558848, 4202179, 1172258, ...]` I've already tried `y.replace(',','')` and other stuff

Comment: It's clear now. You should get the answer you need in the modified code, Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve your problem:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
x = []
y = []
with open('Nickels.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        d1 = line.strip().split('-')   # Splits X and Y constituents
        if len(d1) !=2: continue       # Skips the empty lines

        d2 = d1[1].strip().split(',')  # Splits Y columns
        if len(d2) !=3: continue       # Skips range lines

        x.append(int(d1[0].strip()))   # Builds X
        y.append(int(''.join(d2)))     # Builds Y
```

Contents of x:

```
[1913, 1914, 1915, 1916, 1917, 1918, 1919, 1920, 1921, 1922]
```

Contents of y:

```
[5588048,
 4202179,
 1172258,
 2481675,
 5521373,
 6052289,
 7835400,
 10649851,
 2582495,
 4763186]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Èbe. This will help me plot the mintage of Canadian coins! Any tips for making coding easier? I read about the methods I'm using, but it's difficult using them in practice

Comment: @Michael  You're welcome! How much experience do you have with Python and other languages?

Comment: I'm a 4th year physics major minoring in CS so I've taken 5 computer science classes so far but only 2 really involved coding (C++).  Also I worked with Python as a full time job one summer but that was over a year ago.

Comment: @Michael Then you'd have no trouble picking it back up from where you left off. I've learnt Python in Coursera from Dr. Charles Severance. I was a pure Java code writer before and was easy to make the transition as I was comfortable with programming logic (B.E. and M.E. in CS). After that, Stack Overflow had been a great support for simple problems in my research projects. It's only rightful to return the favour to the community.